# Selenium c# как двигать мышкой?

Tags: c#, selenium, hover

пытаюсь зайти в меню, активируемое по hover и кликнуть на элемент.
Например:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp

Как послать ввод с клавиатуры я нашел, например:
 SearchInput.SendKeys("как вырастить гомункула" + OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);

А вот обработка перемещения мыши мне не далась.

В интернете написано что вроде должен работать такой код:

```
IWebElement pictClick = Browser.FindElement(By.Id("pv_nav_btn_right"));

Actions action = new Actions(Browser);
action.MoveToElement(pictClick);
action.Build();
action.Perform();
```

Почему то у меня он не сработал.
Подскажите пожалуйста как в Selenium можно двигать мышкой так, чтобы вызывалось hover ?

Answer (score 1):

Код для джавы, но, в общем, код для шарпа должен быть идентичным (только размеры букв местами не будут совпадать):

```
WebElement el = driver.findElementById("elementId");

Coordinates c = (RemoteWebElement)el).getCoordinates();

driver.getMouse().mouseMove(c);
```

---

Если же ты хочешь двигать мышку физически, то тебе нужно смотреть в сторону WinAPI